# What is the best way to logically combine search results from different sources?

Tags: javascript, search, logic

I am searching for songs on multiple sites (youtube, vimeo etc..)
and want to show the user a unified list of the results. 
After I gather the results from all source, I combine them into one list - 
but how can I determine the best way to order the list, based on the user
initial search query?

I am using javascript, but this question is more about logic than code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**First** You have to remove duplicates as you can

**Second** You can give a rating for each website to sort with.

**For example** You can give youtube 5 rating + rating from youtube itself (if you have it)
then Vimeo 4 rating + rating from viemo itself (if you have it)

**Third** You can sort with the most relevant result returned to you

**Forth** You can get data with the most relevant result from service provider